# C++ undefined reference to XXX in function XXX

Tags: c++, types, reference, makefile

I put up an own type in the header:

```
typedef int OperationId;

struct operation{
  OperationId                                 id;
  JobId                                       assignedJob;
  MachineType                                 machineType;
  double                                      earning;
  std::vector<operation>                      operationPredecessors_;
  std::vector<operation>::iterator            oPredecessorsIterator;
  std::vector<operation>                      operationSuccessors_;
  std::vector<operation>::iterator            oSuccessorsIterator;
  double                                      processingTime;
  std::vector<Machine>                        operationMachines_;
  std::vector<Machine>::iterator              oMachinesIterator;
};
```

which uses other custom types.
Now I made myself some function to create Operations since I dont want to write that much code all the time with every Operation:

```
operation createOperation  (  operation    o,
                              OperationId  id, 
                              MachineType  type,
                              double       earning,
                              double       processingTime);
```

and that in the .cpp:

```
operation createOperation ( operation      o,  
                            OperationId    id, 
                            MachineType    type,
                            double         earning,
                            double         processingTime){
  o.id               = id;
  o.machineType      = type;
  o.earning          = earning;
  o.processingTime   = processingTime;
  return o;
}
```

Now as I call the cunction with:

```
OperationId id;
operation oSzero;
id = 0;
oSzero    = createOperation(oSzero,id,INCOMING_GOODS,0,20);
```

It gives me the following error:

```
undefined reference to Schedule::createOperation(operation, int, MachineType, double, double)'
```

Anybody any idea why? I am using make as a compiler. It was working perfectly without the function and:

```
oSzero.id = 0;
oSzero.MachineType = INCOMING_GOODS;
....
```

etc. in the main directly.

Comment: BTW, `createOperation` may be a constructor of `operation` (as you tag your Q C++).

Comment: Schedule is a class. However I defined operation outside of the class since I am using it in other classes as well and want to have it global. The function I am calling createOperation in however is part of Schedule.

Comment: I now solved the issue! It was a pure beginners error. As "createOperation" is part of schedule obviously I have to define it with Schedule::createOperation in the .cpp - thanks however for your thoughts! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you do something like:

```
class Schedule {
public:
    operation createOperation(operation o,
                              OperationId  id, 
                              MachineType  type,
                              double       earning,
                              double       processingTime);
};
```

And then

```
operation createOperation(operation o,
                          OperationId  id, 
                          MachineType  type,
                          double       earning,
                          double       processingTime)
{
    /* code */
}
```

So, you have several choice:

Move declaration of `createOperation` outside of Schedule

or do the implemantation of `Schedule::createOperation` as:

```
operation Schedule::createOperation(operation o,
                          OperationId  id, 
                          MachineType  type,
                          double       earning,
                          double       processingTime)
{
    /* code */
}
```

But I suggest to create a constructor:

```
struct operation{
    operation(OperationId id, MachineType type, double earning, double processingTime);
    // previous stuff
};

operation::operation(OperationId id, MachineType type, double earning, double processingTime) :
  id(id),
  machineType(type),
  earning(earning),
  processingTime(processingTime)
{
  // any other initialization
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my issue. I earlier tried to implement it as a constructor, which caused other problems in other regions of my code. So now I correctly implemented createOperation inside Schedule:: - thanks again for the answer!